# Ros2 install / Unable to locate package

Tags: ros2, ros-crystal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi together,

I have some trouble installing ROS2 on Lubuntu 18.04 on a Asus Think Board.
I tried the installation manual at https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Crystal/Linux-Install-Debians/ for crystal and also for dashing. Both of them don't work for me and I get

> E: Unable to locate package ros-crystal-ros-base

Here is my Terminal in-&output:

```
tinker@ELAR-Systems:~$ sudo locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8
[sudo] password for tinker: 
tSorry, try again.
[sudo] password for tinker: 
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  en_US.ISO-8859-1... done
  en_US.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.

tinker@ELAR-Systems:~$ sudo apt update && sudo apt install curl gnupg2 lsb-release
Hit:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
lsb-release is already the newest version (9.20170808ubuntu1).
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  curl gnupg2 libcurl4
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 341 kB of archives.
After this operation, 831 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/main armhf libcurl4 armhf 7.58.0-2ubuntu3 [183 kB]
Get:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/main armhf curl armhf 7.58.0-2ubuntu3 [152 kB]
Get:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/universe armhf gnupg2 all 2.2.4-1ubuntu1 [4,984 B]
Fetched 341 kB in 1s (582 kB/s)   
Selecting previously unselected package libcurl4:armhf.
(Reading database ... 100850 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libcurl4_7.58.0-2ubuntu3_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libcurl4:armhf (7.58.0-2ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package curl.
Preparing to unpack .../curl_7.58.0-2ubuntu3_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking curl (7.58.0-2ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gnupg2.
Preparing to unpack .../gnupg2_2.2.4-1ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking gnupg2 (2.2.4-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libcurl4:armhf (7.58.0-2ubuntu3) ...
Setting up gnupg2 (2.2.4-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2) ...
Setting up curl (7.58.0-2ubuntu3) ...

tinker@ELAR-Systems:~$ curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.asc | sudo apt-key add -
OK

tinker@ELAR-Systems:~$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64,arm64] http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu `lsb_release -cs` main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2-latest.list'

tinker@ELAR-Systems:~$ export CHOOSE_ROS_DISTRO=crystal

tinker@ELAR-Systems:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu bionic InRelease [3,209 B]
Get:3 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages [344 kB]
Get:4 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages [331 kB]
Fetched 679 kB in 2s (286 kB/s)   
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.

tinker@ELAR-Systems:~$ sudo apt install ros-$CHOOSE_ROS_DISTRO-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-crystal-desktop

tinker@ELAR-Systems:~$ sudo apt install ros-$CHOOSE_ROS_DISTRO-ros-base
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-crystal-ros-base
```

btw: the holdback package is only Firefox

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328717/ros2-install-/-unable-to-locate-package/) by [MrCheesecake](https://answers.ros.org/users/44078/mrcheesecake/) on ROS Answers with karma: 272 on 2019-07-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This confuses me slightly:

> ```
> Get:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/main armhf libcurl4 armhf 7.58.0-2ubuntu3 [183 kB]
> ```

but then:

> ```
> Get:3 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages [344 kB]
> ```

```
Get:4 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages [331 kB]
```

Assuming you're actually running an `armhf` platform:

If I interpret [REP-2000: ROS 2 Target Platforms - Platforms by Distribution - Crystal Clemmys (December 2018 - December 2019)](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html#crystal-clemmys-december-2018-december-2019) correctly, it would appear there are no binary packages for the `armhf` architecture (neither on Ubuntu nor Debian).

Only `arm64` is supported by the buildfarm.

It appears Dashing has support for `arm32` ([here](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html#dashing-diademata-may-2019-may-2021)).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MrCheesecake](https://answers.ros.org/users/44078/mrcheesecake/) on 2019-07-19**:
You are correct. It's armhf architecture.
Unfortunately there are no Dashing arm32 packages and building also don't work for me(in the manual is no apt repository for arm32), not like described in the REP-2000.
Building crystal works for me on 16.04 (without rviz).
So does anyone knows when arm32 repositories are added or where I can get the package or sources?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-19**:
You're probably running into [ros2/ros2#721](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/issues/721).

Perhaps @nuclearsandwich can say something about the ETA of `armhf` pkgs for Bionic.